# How to go through JSON Array and add Data in to array - react-native

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

Im tring to add json object to array.so i can add array to my Flat list compoentnt.but i cant understand how to add data array.

this is my code

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Vehicle_Details :[],

        }

var text = JSON.parse(jobs);
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    console.log(text[i]["Vehicle_Details"]);
                    this.setState({
                    Vehicle_Details:(text[i])
                    })
                }
```

but this added last object only.how can i solve this?

Comment: is obvious as you are overwriting it, whats the content of `jobs`?

Comment: its my json responce.
' [{"Vehicle_Details":"Civic","Transmission":"Manual"},{"Vehicle_Details":"fit","Transmission":"Manual"}]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are parsing JSON in constructor itself. there is no need to call `setState`, you can directly assign state.

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);    

  var text = JSON.parse(jobs);
  this.state = {
    Vehicle_Details: text.map(function(item) {
      return item['Vehicle_Details']
    })
  }
}
```